# Can the "Code Sample" button be made to work with list items and blockquotes?

Tags: feature-request

If I type this

```
1.  You could try this

callSomeFunction();

2.  Or this

callSomeOtherFunction();
```

Selecting `callSomeFunction()` and clicking the `{}` button does not indent correctly. It only moves the code to here

```
1.  You could try this

    callSomeFunction();
```

which is wrong and will not show as code even though I clicked the *Code Sample* `{}` button. That seems like a long standing bug. Are there any plans to fix this?