# Indent 8 spaces when clicking the Code Sample button after a list item

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

In order to format code in a numbered or bulleted list, you need to [indent it eight spaces](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255373/3681880) instead of the usual four. [This is by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255372/code-block-bug-when-following-numbered-list).

If the Sample Code button is pressed when a user has a block of code highlighted, it automatically indents everything four lines. This is very useful.

[image]

**Feature request**

I request that if the highlighted block of code follows a list item, that every line be automatically indented 8 spaces instead of 4.

In the current situation I have to add the additional spaces to every line by hand. This is inconvenient.

**Duplicate**

This question is a duplicate.

- It was asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326550/automatically-indent-code-the-correct-amount-under-numbered-lists), but the question was unclear and misunderstood to be a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255372/code-block-bug-when-following-numbered-list).
- It was also asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316060/can-the-code-sample-button-be-made-to-work-with-list-items-and-blockquotes) but has received no response.
- This a list item. It is unrelated to the rest of the list.

  ```
  // I pressed the Sample Code button but then had to add an extra 4 spaces by hand in order to make this be formatted as code. I don't really mind doing this for a single line of code, but for multiple lines it is kind of a pain.
  ```

Comment: Work around: Install this [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript) and then you can use tab/shift tab to indent/outdent code blocks.  Then all you have to do is paste the code, select it, and then press tab twice.

Comment: I would in general support a feature that lets you indent already indented code even further. It would make repairing someone's indentation spaghetti a lot easier.

Comment: Ahhh! that's why the editor doesn't work all the time. I've always taught this was due to some bugs within the editor. Good suggestion!

Comment: @NathanOliver, nice. I had never used user scripts before. It wasn't too hard to install.

Comment: If you search the comments on previous issues great Jon Skeet declared that putting code in list items is *doing things wrong* and thus it was so. Good look with your request.

Comment: You can always add a dot `.` (or any other character) at the start of a newly added line just after the code block and then indent the code block plus the line with the dot again, and then remove the line with the dot on it.  That's not incredibly sophisticated, but it works, and is easier than indenting a multi-line block of code by 4 spaces manually.  And I see this is what [halfer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) suggests in this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348213/).

Answer (score 35):

Just a suggestion.

I believe that this kind of feature request could be accepted much faster if accompanied by the *pull request*.

Although Stack Overflow as a whole is not open source, some of its parts are. And the part in question is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Editor.js), waiting for pull requests. So I believe that the community can handle this kind of feature requests itself.

To answer the request for clarification: I were writing this under the impression that some JS pro would stumble upon this topic, willing to contribute. Who will post a draft proposal with a discussion ensued which will end up with a community-proposed pull request. Sort of crowdsourcing. You know - community spirit, all that stuff.

Comment: And more precisely [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Editor.js#L2099)

Comment: This is a good idea, though I guess it would be worth hearing from SO that they'd be willing to implement it before going to that effort. The SO team still have to schedule the work into their sprint.

Comment: I don't like this defeatist attitude, when you are ready to surrender even without trying.

Comment: What is a *pull request*? Does it mean "implement your requested feature by yourself"? You might want to clarify your answer.

Comment: @anatolyg: Yes. Git uses "pull requests" to ask someone to "pull" your fork of their repository containing your changes, and "pull requests welcome" is a common phrase used in Git-based open source projects to welcome largely-complete coding contributions — or brush off anything that's *not* largely complete. After all, if you really wanted something, surely you would be able to code up most of it yourself and the project maintainers can simply review and finish integrating if it suits their vision.

Comment: @halfer If that were the case, nobody would ever submit a pull request; all we'd have were tickets. +1 to YCS' sentiment.

Comment: @Qix I'd never make a pull request to a project unless I either needed it for myself anyway for my copy of a project, or I was sure that they were interested in the feature.  I have better things to do than submit code that isn't going to be looked at.  I might be willing to do it after I was assured they were interested, but otherwise I have projects of my own, a job of my own, and passions other than programming to work on.  Posting somewhere like here to see if they're interested is usually the best first step.

Comment: @Qix: I am not disagreeing with someone outside of SE doing the work themselves. But it is quite normal in F/OSS projects to consult with the core committers before embarking on work. This is to avoid going off in the wrong direction, doing incompatible work, etc. Not all submissions to F/OSS projects are merged in.

Comment: @halfer Sure, if the work takes a long time, then I would do that myself. What would be required in this PR is not going to be more than maybe a few hours of work. No need to consult about roadmaps, long term visions or core committees.

Comment: I understand @Qix, and if you want to do that work without any nod first, that's up to you. I think it is still prudent to get agreement first, to save wasting development time.

Comment: @halfer Have you worked in open source? That's not how anything gets done.

Comment: It is a rather trivial point, so shall we agree to disagree, @Qix?

Answer (score 20):

I support this feature request.

A work-around for now is to:

- Select the unindented code block
- Click the code button to indent it to four spaces
- Manually unindent the first line
- Select the whole block again
- Click the code button again to indent it to eight spaces
- Repair the first line

It's a bit of a faff, but it's useful on large blocks of code.

Comment: You can also type a single character (a point for example) on the first blanck line before the code and remove it after